# How to load Web Assembly scripts in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webassembly

I'm not sure this is even possible, and if it is I assume we need to make use of WebViews, but perhaps I'm overthinking things. I haven't found any information on this anywhere.

Comment: What tooling are you using to generate the WebAssembly module?

Comment: It's WebAssembly from an `npm` module. Is there some importance to how it's generated?

Comment: I doubt it. Just trying to get a fuller picture of what is being done. Sometimes there are weird interactions.

Comment: Does WebView support WebAssembly?

Comment: @yushulx, it does.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [react-native-react-bridge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-react-bridge), which requests a webview that you can load your WebAssembly module through. Haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Interesting. Let me know if you try it. To be an accepted answer I'd like to see sample code or a link to exactly how to implement this. (Bonus points if it supports Expo; I don't think it does.)